# Can I create a file download on my html site that only includes the "save" button, not the open button?

Tags: php, html, file, download

my code is below.  This works, but I am wondering if there is a way to exclude the "Open" button and force the user to save the file.  Thank you!

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("myfile.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: No. That's a browser option not an http header. Have you ever been to a site where you got save but not open option?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
readfile("myfile.pdf");
?>
```

put this code in another file say file.php then call it using anchor tag

```
<a href='file.php'>Download PDF</a>
```